# MapPolygon.StrokeThickness blurred when App runs on Mobile

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, windows-10-mobile

as described in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapPolygon#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Maps_MapPolygon_StrokeThickness) `MapPolygon.StrokeThickness` holds the thickness of the outer stroke of the polygon on a `MapControl` in logical pixels. When I'm correct, that ensures that the line seems to have the same thickness on all devices, independent of dpi scaling.

That worked for my app till recently, but since a few new builds of Windows 10 Mobile, that line is drawed blurred, the edges of the dashes are rounded. Have a look at the attached image, comparing my UWP app running on mobile and desktop.

Why are the stroke lines of a `MapPolygon` blurred, enlarged, and rounded on recent versions of mobile? I did not find any change in documentation/spec. Do I have to adjust some parameters on newer versions of Win10 Mobile? Is this a known bug?

App is an UWP app, compiled with VS2015, target = Windows 10 14393, min = Windows 10 10586.

EDIT: As the answer confirms, this is a known bug. I found out that using `MapPolyline` instead of `MapPolygon` is a workaround. For `MapPolyline` DPI scaling works fine and I get no blurred lines (but also no `FillColor`).

[image: Comparing of StrokeThickness on Desktop and Mobile]

Thanks

Comment: What's the OS Biuld you are using while testing on Mobile? Are you using Build 10.0.15007?

Comment: At the moment it's 15043. But it's blurry since 15007 (I guess, not sure).

Comment: This should be fixed in more recent builds. DPI scaling was being incorrectly applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback. We have confirmed this issue internally. As @Duncan Lawler's comment said, this should be fixed in more recent builds. Please wait for the release of new OS Build. If you notice any other glitches in UWP apps, please feel free to provide feedback. Your feedback has made Windows better!

Comment: Thanks for that confirmation. Good to know that I just have to wait, there is no need for any changes.